# RangeType Symfony with array attr

Tags: symfony, symfony4

How can i use array inside a RangeType?, in a form: If use this, the array works but the range type attr for min and max no.

```
->add('enddate', RangeType::class, array( 'attr' => array ('oninput' => 'day.value = demand_enddate.value')), [
            'attr' => [
               'min'   => 1,
               'max'   => 31
            ]
        ])
```

It's really tedious works with forms, at least for me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

NVM, I just was blinded:

```
->add('enddate', RangeType::class, [
            'attr' => [
               'min'   => 1,
               'max'   => 31,
               'oninput'   => 'day.value = demand_enddate.value'
            ]
        ])
```

Works as expected.